# AccessViolationException in Gl.DrawArrays

Tags: c#, opengl, access-violation

I am using [OpenGL.net](http://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/wiki) (Available through NuGet) with C# and I am trying to put together a minimal working example for modern OpenGL.

Clearing the screen and Shader Conpilation works, however I am getting an **AccessViolationException** in the **Gl.DrawArrays** call on **line 158.**

**What I have done so far:**

- Reassured Vertex Data is uploaded
- Checked the count argument in Gl.DrawArrays is correct
- Checked Shaders are correct and compiled
- Checked Size Arguments are correct everywhere
- Gone through the first few pages of google links on the error  message in context with OpenGL and c#

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using OpenGL;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;

namespace RenderEngine
{
    public class RenderForm : Form
    {
        private Timer tmr_Render;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        private GlControl glc_screen;
        MemoryLock vertexArrayLock;
        uint vertexArrayID;
        uint vertexbuffer;
        uint shaderProgram;
        private static readonly float[] _ArrayPosition = new float[] {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
        };

        private static readonly float[] _ArrayColor = new float[] {
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };


        public RenderForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.glc_screen = new OpenGL.GlControl();
            this.tmr_Render = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // glc_screen
            // 
            this.glc_screen.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
            this.glc_screen.ColorBits = ((uint)(24u));
            this.glc_screen.DepthBits = ((uint)(0u));
            this.glc_screen.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.glc_screen.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.glc_screen.MultisampleBits = ((uint)(0u));
            this.glc_screen.Name = "glc_screen";
            this.glc_screen.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 561);
            this.glc_screen.StencilBits = ((uint)(0u));
            this.glc_screen.TabIndex = 0;
            this.glc_screen.ContextCreated += new System.EventHandler<OpenGL.GlControlEventArgs>(this.glc_screen_ContextCreated);
            this.glc_screen.Render += new System.EventHandler<OpenGL.GlControlEventArgs>(this.glc_screen_Render);
            // 
            // tmr_Render
            // 
            this.tmr_Render.Enabled = true;
            this.tmr_Render.Interval = 16;
            this.tmr_Render.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmr_Render_Tick);
            // 
            // RenderForm
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 561);
            this.Controls.Add(this.glc_screen);
            this.Name = "RenderForm";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void glc_screen_ContextCreated(object sender, GlControlEventArgs e)
        {
            GlControl glControl = (GlControl)sender;

            shaderProgram = LoadShaders("../../../RenderEngine/vertex.shader", "../../../RenderEngine/fragment.shader");

            vertexArrayID = Gl.GenVertexArray();
            Gl.BindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
            Gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexArrayID);

            vertexArrayLock = new MemoryLock(_ArrayPosition);
            vertexbuffer = Gl.GenBuffer();
            Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer, vertexbuffer);
            Gl.BufferData(BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer, /*sizeof(float)*(uint)_ArrayPosition.Length*/ 100, vertexArrayLock.Address, BufferUsageARB.DynamicDraw);
            int indexInShader = 0;// Gl.GetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertexPosition_modelspace");
            int floatsPerVertex = 2;
            bool normalized = false;
            int stride = floatsPerVertex*sizeof(float);
            int arrayBufferOffset = 0;
            Gl.VertexAttribPointer((uint)indexInShader, floatsPerVertex, Gl.FLOAT, normalized, stride, arrayBufferOffset);
            Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        private uint LoadShaders(string vertexPath, string fragmentPath) {
            uint vertexShaderId = Gl.CreateShader(Gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            uint fragmentShaderId = Gl.CreateShader(Gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

            string vertexCode = File.ReadAllText(vertexPath);
            string fragmentCode = File.ReadAllText(fragmentPath);

            int vertexResult;
            int vertexInfoLogLength;
            StringBuilder vertexInfoLog = new StringBuilder(200);
            Gl.ShaderSource(vertexShaderId, new string[] { vertexCode }/*vertexCode.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })*/);
            Gl.CompileShader(vertexShaderId);
            Gl.GetShader(vertexShaderId, Gl.COMPILE_STATUS, out vertexResult);
            Gl.GetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderId, 200, out vertexInfoLogLength, vertexInfoLog);
            Console.WriteLine(vertexInfoLog.Length == 0 ? "Vertex shader compiled sucessfully" : vertexInfoLog.ToString());

            int fragmentResult;
            int fragmentInfoLogLength;
            StringBuilder fragmentInfoLog = new StringBuilder(200);
            Gl.ShaderSource(fragmentShaderId, new string[] { fragmentCode }/*fragmentCode.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })*/);
            Gl.CompileShader(fragmentShaderId);
            Gl.GetShader(fragmentShaderId, Gl.COMPILE_STATUS, out fragmentResult);
            Gl.GetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderId, 200, out fragmentInfoLogLength, fragmentInfoLog);
            Console.WriteLine(fragmentInfoLog.Length==0 ? "Fragment shader compiled sucessfully" : fragmentInfoLog.ToString());

            uint programId = Gl.CreateProgram();
            Gl.AttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
            Gl.AttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);
            Gl.LinkProgram(programId);
            int programResult;
            int programInfoLogLength;
            StringBuilder programInfoLog = new StringBuilder(200);
            Gl.GetProgram(programId, Gl.LINK_STATUS, out programResult);
            Gl.GetProgramInfoLog(programId, 200, out programInfoLogLength, programInfoLog);
            Console.WriteLine(programInfoLog.Length == 0 ? "Program linked sucessfully" : programInfoLog.ToString());

            Gl.DetachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
            Gl.DetachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);

            Gl.DeleteShader(vertexShaderId);
            Gl.DeleteShader(fragmentShaderId);

            return programId;
        }

        private void glc_screen_Render(object sender, GlControlEventArgs e)
        {
            GlControl senderControl = (GlControl)sender;

            Gl.BindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);
            Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer, vertexbuffer);


            Gl.CheckErrors();
            Console.WriteLine(Gl.GetError());
            int floatsPerVertex = 2;
            int start = 0;
            int verticies = _ArrayPosition.Length / floatsPerVertex;
            Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
            Gl.ClearColor(1f, .5f, 1f, 0f);
            Gl.UseProgram(shaderProgram);
            Gl.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, start, verticies);

            Gl.DisableVertexAttribArray(vertexArrayID);
        }

        private void tmr_Render_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            glc_screen.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertexPosition_modelspace;
void main() {
    gl_Position.xy = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.z = 1.0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
void main() {
    color = vec4(1, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I have no clue what is wrong at this point, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be this help: [OpenGl.net Pointer arguments](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/wiki/GL-%5C-Common-mistakes#pointer-arguments)

Comment: @Ripi2 I am already using the MemoryLocks as suggested, but thanks for the effort. I am glad for any suggestion :)

Comment: "Access violation" means an invalid pointer, usually "0".

Comment: @Ripi2 I see... But how do I debug something like that? I cannot hook into NuGet Libraries, right?

Comment: Use MemoryLocks for "verticies" right before DrawArrays.

Comment: @Ripi2 I will try in 5 minutes... but isn't the whole point of the memory lock that it locks the thing in place? Then it should be sufficient to do it once at the start and then keep itt, right?

Comment: Lock while reading (or passing) the pointer. Unlock before writting data to that pointer.

Comment: @Ripi2 That did not fix it, sadly :/ No change at all. But definitely worth a try.

Comment: @Ripi2 MemoryLock should lock memory till is necessary. In this case it's necessary untill Gl.BufferSubData has returned. From that point, the buffer object has stored the CPU data, and the pointer is not required to be pinned anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that

```
Gl.BufferData(BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer, /*sizeof(float)*(uint)_ArrayPosition.Length*/ 100, vertexArrayLock.Address, BufferUsageARB.DynamicDraw);
```

is the root of the problem. You are telling to OpenGL to define a buffer of 100 bytes, and initialize the content from `vertexArrayLock.Address`. Sadly, `vertexArrayLock.Address` points to a memory large 6 * sizeof(float) = 24 bytes.

However, I don't understand why you're getting exception on `DrawArrays`; probably there are other issues I didn't see.

--- Few minutes later ---

Got it. Remove the line:

```
Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer, 0);
```

from `glc_screen_ContextCreated`. It will alter the VAO state in a way that no buffer is used. Focus of VAO state vector, and you'll get a successfull DrawArrays.

Comment: I just figured put you are the author of Opengl.net. Great work, keep it up!